# TinyMCE Buttons on Certain Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

I'm creating a plugin that will allow users to create custom post types on the fly.

On the new post types, I want a custom
Button to show In the TinyMCE.

Each of the post types has a unique description, so I want to add the buttons based on the post type description.

Something like:

```
 if ($post_type->description == 'Custom Description') { 

 // Add TinyMCE Button Here

}
```

To get the post type description, I found another post that suggested:

```
get_post_type_object($post);
$post_type->description;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working correctly for me.

Any ideas how to add the TinyMCE buttons to a post type that has a certain post type description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used in one of my plugins and working well, hopefully it can draw some inspiration:

```
public function efpd_run_tinymce(){
    global $typenow, $pagenow;

    if ( empty( $typenow ) && !empty( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $_GET['post'] );
        $typenow = $post->post_type;
    }

    $curpage = $pagenow . 'post-new.php?post_type=' . $typenow;

    if( 'fanpages' == $typenow || 'post-new.php?post-type=fanpages' == $curpage ) {

        if( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) )
           return;

        if( get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) == 'true' ) {

            add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array( &$this, 'efpd_tinymce_plugins' ) );
            add_filter( 'mce_buttons_3', array( &$this, 'efpd_tinymce_buttons' ) );

        }

    }

}
```

I think potentially you could take `$typenow` and get the post type object and then use the description instead of the logic I've used in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've never used $typenow for anything, so I did some research on it and while it doesn't help me, it lead me to an AWESOME article about custom post types. . .http://www.astronautdesigns.com/2011/12/wordpress-custom-post-type-boilerplate-part-1/

Comment: So. . .after some more research. . .inspired by the article I found. . .because of your comment, I figured out my way of getting the description was flawed. 

Instead of `get_post_type_object($post);` I should have used `$post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post));`

All is working now, but the forum won't allow me to answer my own question yet. 

I'll post the answer when I'm allowed.

Thanks for your input!!

Comment: Essentially that is the same as doing `get_post_type_object( $typenow )` :) but I'm glad you figured it out!